# Why is iterator of container invalidated when this container is also an element of a container?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    v.push_back({1,2,3,4});

    auto it = v.at(0).begin();
    int size = v.at(0).size();
    std::cout<<size<<std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++it)
    {
        v.push_back({5,6,7,8});
        //std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The iterator is broken when I push some elements into the outer container.
what should I do if I really want to iterate the container element inside of outer container and at the same time keep pushing back some new elements ? Many thanks!

Comment: The `push_back` inside the loop reallocates the array used by the outer vector, which in turn reallocates the inner vectors, moving them (and their arrays) to new memory addresses. That is why the iterator is invalidated

Comment: One option: use an index rather than iterators to loop over the inner vector.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the note [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) states that the inner vector's iterator should *not* be invalidated when it is moved. Given that, I don't actually see why this code would fail...

Comment: Yes, use index is a partial solution if inner container is a sequential container. If I use vector<map<int, X>>, I cannot find easy way to iterate inner container.

Comment: @Quentin: AFAIK, the reallocation doesn't use the move constructor, so that note doesn't apply

Comment: @RemyLebeau why wouldn't it? Everything here is `noexcept`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the outer vector resizes, it must do one of two things:

- copy the elements
- move the elements

It can only move the elements if the type has nonthrowing move semantics (the move constructor is marked *noexcept*, etc).

In this case, the element is a vector holding integers, which recursively depends on its elements.  Since integer does not throw, the inner vector should be noexcept-movable too.  The standard requires the iterators to remain valid when moving such a vector.

You *say* iterator is broken in your example, but the real problem is a bug in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++it) // << HERE
{
    v.push_back({5,6,7,8});
    //std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
}
```

You don't increment the loop variable, you increment the iterator, in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

> what should I do if I really want to iterate the container element inside of outer container and at the same time keep pushing back some new elements ?

I see 3 possible solutions:

- use container that does not relocate elements when new ones are added, for example `std::map<size_t,std::vector<int>>`, you should be aware of different memory usage and access speed
- use index of inner array instead of iterator
- add data to a temporary vector in the loop and after you done append all data to the original vector

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, there are ways to work around this nuisance problem.